# The PC is not completing the restart process after installation 12.04

Tags: system-installation

My PC was trying to restart to finish installation but it has hung midway through.
The last message it shows is `synchronising SCSi cache`. It's the first reboot after installation of 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing again following the [Official Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall).

It could just be a loose connection.  For this try powering off the computer, unplugging the power cable, a few seconds later touch the metal on the outside of the box to discharge any static electricity, unplug the hard drive cable from both ends, and reconnect everything.

There could be a problem with the hard drive.  The Live CD has several tools to repair the disk, such as:

```
sudo fdisk -l
sudo fsck /dev/yourdisk
sudo badblocks -sv /dev/yourdisk
```

`fdisk` will show you all the drives that are accessable.  `fsck` will check and repair the file system.  `badblocks` will actually search the physical disk for parts that are bad.  [Disk Utility](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/37659/the-beginners-guide-to-linux-disk-utilities/) is a GUI tool used for the same thing.  [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) is another option.

The log files are extremely useful for troubleshooting.  You can view your logs from terminal like this:

```
cd /var/logs
less syslog
```

As mentioned in the [LinuxLogFiles](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles) Wiki, you can browse them like this:

```
"Press h for help, or q to quit. The cursor keys and page up/down keys will work as
expected, and the slash key ("/") will do a case-sensitive search; the n key repeats
the last search."
```

Error logs look like this: /var/log/apport.log and can be found by showing the contents of your logs directory:

```
ls /var/logs
```

You would view it the same way as syslog above. 
Here are a couple resources for troubleshooting:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Troubleshooting 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting